# Get a MYSQL Date into a c# String exception

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, date

I'm trying to extract a date field from a mysql db using .NET and MySQL .NET Connector.

Whithin the test everything works great except the date, I mean, I can get the varchar fields but the DATE field (called R_DATE) is impossible.

My SQL Query is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

And, the way I'm trying to read it is:

```
DateTime date = reader.GetDateTime(COLUM_INDEX);
```

I just don't know what to do. I prove to explicity put the SELECT A, B, C... and didn't work, also tryed with SELECT A, DATE_FORMAT(B, '...) but also didn't.

Anything wrong?

Thanks for the help. Any tip will be very valuable.

EXCEPTION

```
Test method DocumentsManagementServiceTest.DataManagerTest.TestSearch threw exception: 
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

Comment: what's the exception you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test if the value is null before calling this method:

```
DateTime? date = null;
if (!reader.IsDBNull(COLUM_INDEX))
{
    date = reader.GetDateTime(COLUM_INDEX);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the value Date is not null. I'm testing it against a fully loaded DB Table.

Comment: Actually this works!

Why putting the ? after the DateTime makes it works?

And... THANKS!!!